# Determine which AutoScaling Group a Launch Configuration is attached to

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

**Question:** Is there a way to determine which AutoScaling Group a Launch Configuration is attached to.

**Why do I need to know?** I have a list of existing Launch Configurations and I want to delete one of them.

**Undesirable Solutions:**

- I can get a list of all my AutoScaling Groups and look through each one to determine which Launch Configuration it is using.
- I can just try to delete the Launch Configuration and then having the error tell me which AutoScaling Group it is attached to.

**Desirable Solutions:**

- Query Launch Configuration and have it return which group it is attached to.
- Query all AutoScaling Groups with the Launch Configuration name as a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as of this moment is that [the solution I am looking for does not yet exist](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=468172).

In light of this current lack I have proceeded to evaluate my **Undesirable Solutions**.

I first considered using a try/catch|except block and parsing the error when trying to delete a Launch Configuration that was attached to a group. The cost of parsing was more than I wanted to deal with so I decided to go with looping through the AutoScaling Groups and finding a match for each individual Launch Configuration.

While the solution is less than ideal, it is working quite nicely. I hope to post the code on GitHub shortly so that others can also benefit from it.

Update: 07 August 2013

[Here is some code on GitHub that I have been working on](https://github.com/SunSparc/aws). Hope it is helpful to others.